# Magento 2 compilation error

Tags: magento2

> ERROR -   **Incompatible argument type: Required type:
> \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory. Actual type: array; File:
> Magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Api/Nvp.php**

***Original file - `/Magento2/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php`***

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $customerAddress,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Logger $customLogger,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\ProcessableExceptionFactory $processableExceptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptionFactory $frameworkExceptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($customerAddress, $logger, $customLogger, $localeResolver, $regionFactory, $data);
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        $this->_processableExceptionFactory = $processableExceptionFactory;
        $this->_frameworkExceptionFactory = $frameworkExceptionFactory;
        $this->_curlFactory = $curlFactory;
    }
```

***Override file - `Magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Api/Nvp.php`***

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $customerAddress,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Logger $customLogger,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\ProcessableExceptionFactory $processableExceptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptionFactory $frameworkExceptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($customerAddress, $logger, $customLogger, $localeResolver, $regionFactory, $data);
        $this->_countryFactory              = $countryFactory;
        $this->_processableExceptionFactory = $processableExceptionFactory;
        $this->_frameworkExceptionFactory   = $frameworkExceptionFactory;
        $this->_curlFactory                 = $curlFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Any thoughts on this, how to fix this ?

Comment: What is the difference between original and overridden file ? and also that error may you please share the full error ?

Comment: Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory. Actual type: array; File: Overriden file

Comment: I have run di:compile & that error appeared, seems like issue with constructor

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: If i compare these two files what is the difference ?

Comment: I have override mentioned file & added same constructor args as original main file, now in di:compile execution it shows error, there might be issue with type of argument

Comment: you need to give argument type of Modal country factory type , not array type, currently you are passing an argument that is of array type but you should pass the argument that is of Modal Country class type ..

Comment: _countryFactory  I would like to see the code before your constructor - lets talk in chatroom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123734/discussion-between-devhs-and-vibhore-jain).

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: Thanks @VibhoreJain for suggestions on fixing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution it can help you in solving this problem 
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Incompatible-Argument-Type-Required-Collection-Factory/m-p/128809#M7527 
I hope it will help you.